# How to draw a colorful 1D histogram in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a 1D array X which contains the statistical data of correlation coefficients, and I want to plot a colorful histogram. I use the following code:

```
histogram(X,10)
```

which can create a histogram with single color, now I want to plot a histogram with each single bar having different colors. But the 'FaceColor' option can only adjust the total color of the entire plot. Can anyone tells me how to achieve that?

Comment: You might have to resort to plotting the histogram "manually" using `bar()`, or go through each of the children of the histogram to change each colour individually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have that level of control over the `histogram` object, instead you have to use a `bar` plot, where the height of each bar is best calculated with `histcounts`.

```
[h,edges] = histcounts(x,10); % calculate the histogram data
b = bar( (edges(1:end-1)+edges(2:end))/2, h ); % plot the bar chart
b.BarWidth = 1; % make the bars full width to look the same as 'histogram'
b.CData = parula( 10 ); % generate colours as a 10x3 array (columns are RGB), can 
                        % do this manually if you want
b.FaceColor = 'flat';   % Make 'bar' use the CData colours
```

[image: bar charts]